# Написание CMAKE для работы с vulkan и glfw

Tags: c, cmake, makefile

На QT Creator для создания приложения с использованием VulkanAPI и GLFW необходимо написать скрипт для CMAKE, однако в этой системе сборки я почти не разбираюсь. Я могу написать команду для gcс, но никак не получается со CMAKE.
Хедеры вулкан лежат тут /home/sergey/library/VulkanApi/1.1.106.0/x86_64/include, библиотеки тут /home/sergey/library/VulkanApi/1.1.106.0/x86_64/include библиотеки GLFW тут /usr/local/lib, а хедеры тут /usr/local/include. К тому же я использую эту команду `pkg-config --static --libs glfw3` для того чтобы скомпоновать библиотеку статически

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В директории, где лежит Ваш проект, создайте файл приблизительно такого содержания:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(my_project)                                                                                              

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O1 -g1 -Wall -rdynamic")
# -O1   Оптимизировать. Компилятор пробует уменьшить размер кода и времяисполнения.
# -g1   Отладка. Уровень 1 выводит минимальную информацию,
#       достаточную, чтобы отслеживать цепочку вызовов.
# -Wall         Предупреждения компиллятора - по максимум

# Поддиректории, содержащие нужные h-файлы
include_directories(
 .
  /home/sergey/library/VulkanApi/1.1.106.0/x86_64/include
)

#  Библиотеки, которые нужны для сборки главной цели
target_link_libraries(my_project
 glfw3
  . . .
 pthread
 mysqlclient
}

# Главная цель - исполняемый модуль my_project
add_executable(my_project
 main.cpp
 a.cpp
 b.cpp
  . . .
)
```

В директории проекта выполните команды:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Есть **очень** хорошая книжка про cmake: Д. В. ДУБРОВ, "СИСТЕМА ПОСТРОЕНИЯ ПРОЕКТОВ CMAKE".  Почитайте - там всё подробно описано.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я пока не могу опробовать ваш код, но заранее ещё раз спасибо. А книгу я прочту

Comment: Выдает ошибку в строке CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "VulkanTest" which is not built by
  this project.
Как я понял он не может найти эти библиотеки. Как задать путь?

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый 1) *Как я понял он не может найти эти библиотеки* -  Совершенно верно. 2) *Как задать путь?* - проще всего добавить опцию компиллятора *-L<Директория Вашей библиотеки>* в оператор  *SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-L,,,,")*